# Retrieve Mongoose Query Queue Time Metrics

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection-pooling, mongoose-plugins

In order to optimize the connection pool size, I thought it would make sense to graph query queue times. Is it possible to retrieve this metric from Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/monitoring) for node monitoring. You need cmap events that apparently aren't documented there, see [Ruby docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#connection-pool-and-connection-monitoring) for example but they should be published by the node driver also.

Track ConnectionCheckOutStarted and ConnectionCheckOutSucceeded and subtract the times to get the wait time.

Comment: Found the node driver documentation for CMAP monitoring: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/a630389bef2cc2a360dacd84d67cf514ed321fdd/docs/reference/content/reference/management/cmap-monitoring.md

Comment: For documentation purposes: These events can be caught with mongoose using `require('mongoose').connection.client.on('connectionCheckedOut', (event) => console.dir(event))`;